# "Unzipped size must be smaller than" with NodejsFunction when in NestedStack

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I am trying to create an L3 construct as a nested stack which will create a lambda function among other things.

We already use NodejsFunction heavily and rely on it's use of esbuild to bundle our functions.

With the construct I need to create a NodejsFunction resource in a nested stack, however I am getting the following error.

```
Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes
```

If I lift the NodejsFunction up to the parent stack, it works fine.

The size of the functions bundle? 3KB

Layers? None

CDK version? Latest

What I have been able to get work is using the more basic `Function` construct, though this isn't really suitable for my stack.

```
    // inside nested stack
    this.lambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'ConsumerExampleLambda', {
      functionName: `consumer-${name}`,
      memorySize: 1024,
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      handler: 'handler',
      environment: {},
      code: lambda.Code.fromInline(`
        exports.handler = async (event) => {
          console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
          return event;
          };
          `),
    });
```

For reference here is my NodejsFunction that I am trying to deploy

```
    this.lambda = new NodejsFunction(this, 'ConsumerExampleLambda', {
      functionName: `consumer-${name}`,
      memorySize: 1024,
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      handler: 'handler',
      bundling: {
        logLevel: LogLevel.WARNING,
        target: 'es2020',
        externalModules: [
          '@nestjs/microservices',
          '@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module',
          '@nestjs/websockets/socket-module',
        ],
      },
      entry: bundling.entry,
    });
```

Comment: Managed to find the asset being uploaded, which is 1GB...
For some reason having the function as a nested stack packages up my entire project as a ZIP. Any ideas why this would happen by simply moving something into a nested stack?